# eCos : Compile and Run sample application on Linux

Tags: c, linux, ecos

I have installed eCos OS on a linux system (Ubuntu 13.02). After installation, the eCos files are located in `opt/ecos`.

As I read the eCos tutorial, I see `hello.c` is stored in `opt/ecos/ecos-3.0/examples/hello.c` (And I notice that maybe all main eCos system files store in the ecos-3.0 directory).

I have followed the eCos tutorial found on the official website, but I still cannot successfully compile hello.c.

More detail. When I try to run :

```non
$ export INSTALL_DIR=BASE_DIR/ecos-work/arm_install 
$ TARGET-gcc -g -IBASE_DIR/ecos-work/install/include hello.c \
    -LBASE_DIR/ecos-work/install/lib -Ttarget.ld -nostdlib
```

I get the error : `TARGET-gcc : command not found`

I have tried some other tutorials, but I'm still having issues (too messy to list here).

I am looking for step-by-step instruction on compiling `hello.c` in eCos system. I see the eCos manual lacking in this area.

Thanks :)

Comment: Why wouldn't you replace "TARGET" with the actual target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you've missed a subtle convention in the eCos [documentation](http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-3.0/user-guide/building-and-running-sample-appliations.html). Items in *italics* are provided by you! They are variables.

The documentation [mentions](http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-3.0/user-guide/compiler-and-linker-options.html) this here:

```
Note: Remember that when this manual shows TARGET-gcc you should use 
the full name of the cross compiler, e.g. i386-elf-gcc, arm-elf-gcc, 
or sh-elf-gcc. When compiling for the synthetic Linux target, use the
native gcc which must have the features required by eCos.
```

Replace *TARGET* with the appropriate value and *BASE_DIR* with (I think, in your case) `/opt/ecos`. You should verify the include directory before moving forward:

```
$ ls -l /opt/ecos/ecos-work/install/include
```

If that doesn't list directory contents, then you simply need to `locate ecos-work`

The [Ecosconfig on Windows and Linux Quick Start](http://ecos.sourceware.org/docs-3.0/user-guide/using-ecosconfig-on-linux.html) section of the docs has you create the *BASE_DIR* directory (below is a snippet that I am quoting ... italics will not display).

```
$ mkdir BASE_DIR/ecos-work
$ cd BASE_DIR/ecos-work
```

So, this could be the correct invocation.

```
$ export INSTALL_DIR=/opt/ecos/ecos-work/arm_install 
$ arm-elf-gcc -g -I/opt/ecos/ecos-work/install/include hello.c \
    -L/opt/ecos/ecos-work/install/lib -Ttarget.ld -nostdlib
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do

```
# source /opt/ecos/ecosenv.sh
```

Then you can try to compile by changing TARGET=

$ TARGET-gcc -g -IBASE_DIR/ecos-work/install/include hello.c \
    -LBASE_DIR/ecos-work/install/lib -Ttarget.ld -nostdlib